# Error when using --static option with macrubyc

Tags: ruby, macos, compilation, macruby, macrubyc

I want to create a binary executable for a relatively simple script that would not require people to install macruby or HotCocoa. [The script is here](http://github.com/gampleman/LESS3/blob/master/utils/postprocessor.rb). I've understood that I want to use the `--static` option for the compiler and I'm using the following command:

```
macrubyc -o postprocessor --static postprocessor.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lLLVMBitWriter
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Error when executing `/usr/bin/g++ -o "postprocessor" -arch x86_64 -L/Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.6/usr/lib -lmacruby-static -L/usr/local/lib  -lpthread -lffi -lm -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMSystem -lpthread -ldl -lxml2 -lobjc -lauto -licucore -framework Foundation  "/var/folders/wU/wUGgoG1JGeKBgwalWLPMAU+++TI/-Tmp-/main-72203.o" "./postprocessor.o"'
```

What should I do to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did just find a solution. Ensure that you're running the version of LLVM specified by MacRuby, and that you're using code from the master branch of MacRuby. It'll take a while to compile everything, but it's worth it.

**In short, if you follow the instructions at [macruby on GitHub](http://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby), you'll be good to go.**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing something from LLVM and [macruby's README](http://github.com/masterkain/macruby) suggests (under Requirements) to install a certain revision of LLVM. So please check wether you have installed it.